# Signal SIGABRT on class AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, swift2, xcode7

I am getting a SigAbrt error when trying to run a iOS app in the simulator in xCode.
The Debug Console says:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

I understand what the exception tells me, however the place where the error occures is the following line:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

So as far as I know this is one of the first lines of code that is executed in additions its a class definiton - I have no Idea how this could trigger such a exception.

Let me know if you need more information such as the call stack.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try adding an exception breakpoint and see what line it directs you to. See the first answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode)[link] for the how-to.

Comment: We would be able to help you if you maybe shared some code.

Comment: Adding exception Breakpoints helped me to identify the problem! It was an error in a closure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to the coding world but resolved the painstaking problem. I was getting the same error by doing something and even though I deleted everything around that I couldn't resolve it. It was still giving me the same error, which meant that it is not deleting in some file it stores. Took me a while to figure out which file, finally when I opened the Mainstoryboard as source file, and did search on the error key word which I knew I changed, it gave me the lines it was sitting in. After deleting those lines error got fixed. I know basic HTML so I knew which lines to delete.

I cannot start my project all over again every time I have this error so I had to find the solution and there was no solution I could find. So I had to do it myself with common sense, as I said I have no knowledge of coding.

Hope it helps.